# Netinstalling CentOS if the gateway is in a different subnet

Tags: networking, centos, virtualization, redhat, kvm-virtualization

I have a KVM host (A) running a virtual machine (B). They each have their own external IP address and the networking is setup using bridging between eth0 and br0 on A. B uses eth0, with A being the gateway.

The problem is that the two external IP addresses are on different subnets (different /8s in fact) so by default, B claims it cannot reach A (Network Unreachable).

I can resolve this by adding a static route on B:
`echo "any host gateway_ip dev eth0" > /etc/sysconfig/static-routes`

Modifying /etc/init.d/networking to reload the gateway after applying static routes (I only added the final line before fi):

```
if [ -f /etc/sysconfig/static-routes ]; then  
    grep "^any" /etc/sysconfig/static-routes | while read ignore args ; do  
        /sbin/route add -$args  
    done  
    route add default gw "${GATEWAY}"  
fi
```

If I then restart networking, it comes online. How can I do this (or work around it some other way) prior to the system being installed, ideally inside an Anaconda kickstart file?

Answer (score 2):

The `/etc/sysconfig/static-routes` file is deprecated, and it uses the `route` command syntax, which is also deprecated.

You can drop rules using the `ip` syntax for the eth0 interface in the file:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0
```

There's no hook to do this directly in a kickstart file, so you would have to do it in the `%post` section.

Comment: The netinstaller needs this to be set before it can start the installation. Am I going to have to find another way to do this? I could install it with NAT/guest and switch to bridging post install I guess.

Comment: Although I don't understand the reasons for your unusual network layout here, my personal preference here would be to install using a basic network config (i.e. NAT), and do final configuration post-install. Creating a "template" VM image per @dynasny's answer is a good idea as well.

Answer (score 1):

since you're running VMs, why not use templates and snapshots instead of kickstarting? Customizations can be put in the `/etc/rc.d/sysinit` file, under

> # Configure machine if /.unconfigured exists:

then run `sys-unconfig` to prepare the VM to become a template.

After this is done, you can clone the images with `qemu-img convert` or take snapshots from the original image, to save disk space, and attach the cloned/snapshotted images to new VMs. They will all have the same configuration and files, minus the typical settings removed by `sys-unconfig`. And whatever else you add to rc.sysinit as well of course.

Comment: Thanks dyasny, I'll take a look over this when I've got a bit of time, it probably does enough for my needs. I'll leave the question open for a couple of days to see if I get a direct answer otherwise I'll always be wondering!

Comment: @JimB there's a sys-unconfig and /etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit on FC14 and CentOS 5. sys-unconfig is provided by initscripts

Comment: oops, you're correct, the old sysconfig file threw me. I'll delete the first comment to not mislead anyone ;)